# How to move back from side menu view controllers to tab bar view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

Here I am using `swrevealViewController` to display side menu and here I am having tab bar for five view controllers and in this every view controller need to have bar button and which will be having action for side menu and here if I select any of the bar buttons in tab bar which will opens side menu and will have access to another view controllers in side menu after going to any view controller then when I press the back button action was working fine and when I move to another to another view controller in tab bar after coming back from view controller then also it works fine whenever I move to previous tab bar view controller and click side menu view controllers then the view controller was moving in the previous navigation controller and in the navigation `frontNVC` the last accessed new view controller was saving in navigation stack can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

here is the code which used for moving side menu

```
        if cell.titleCellLabel.text! == "Account"
        {
            var controller: UIViewController? = nil
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: controllers[indexPath.row])
            print(frontNVC?.viewControllers)
            if controller != nil
            {
                // Prevent stacking the same controller multiple times
                print(frontNVC)
                _ = frontNVC?.popViewController(animated: false)
                frontNVC?.viewControllers.removeAll()
                // Prevent pushing twice FrontTableViewController
                if !(controller is SWRevealViewController) {
                    // Show the controller with the front view controller's navigation controller
                    print(frontNVC)
                    frontNVC!.pushViewController(controller!, animated: false)
                }
                // Set front view controller's position to left
                revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(.left, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

here is the code used for back button action used in side menu view controllers

```
  @IBAction func backButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let nc = revealViewController().rearViewController as? UINavigationController
        let frontNVC = (nc?.topViewController as? LeftSideViewController)?.frontNVC
        _ = frontNVC?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Here is my story board layout image shown below
[image]